# Get selected dropdown value from ionic to php

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, ajax, ionic-framework

I am new in ionic and I am not really familiar of using ajax, and i had a problem in getting the selected value in a drop down and i would like to save it in my database using ajax ..

My view in ionic has 3 option value
   20mins, 30mins, and 1 hour

I want to get the selected value using ng-model. here is the code containing my service.

```
    var returnRecipeData = {};

    return  {

        AddRecipe: function(thisrecipe){


            $http.post('http://localhost/admin-recipick/home/ajaxUserRecipe', thisrecipe).then(function(result){
                console.log(result);
            }, function(err){
                 console.error('ERR', err);
            });
        }
```

here's my controller.

```
    $scope.newRecipe={};

    $scope.AddRecipe = function() {
    console.log("Adding Recipe");
    UserRecipeList.AddRecipe($scope.newRecipe);
    //console.log($scope.signupdata);
    //var registerThis = StudentList.register($scope.signupdata);*/

    if(UserRecipeList.AddRecipe){
      console.log("Recipe Added Successfully");
      $scope.login();
      $ionicPopup.alert({
                  title: 'Recipe Added Successfully!'
              });
    }
    else{
       $ionicPopup.alert({
                  title: 'Failed to Add! Please Try Again!'
              });
    }
```

.. and lastly i want to post the selected value to my sql database using ajax..

```
        $data = array('Recipe_ID'       => null,
                      'Recipename'      => $post->name,
                      'Ingredients'     => $post->ingredients,
                      'Cookingtime'     => $post->ctime,---> this is the part where i want to post the value to my database. but getting an error.
                      'Procedure'       => $post->procedure,
                      'user_id'         => 1

            );
        $this->db->insert('UsersRecipes', $data);
        echo json_encode($this->db->insert_id());
    }
```

... but i had internal server error .. PLEASE HELP..

Comment: try to call web service from third party tools like postman

Comment: did you see a mistake in my code?